# Function input gives error "First variable cannot be a number: 0"

Tags: python, function, math, input

the following function won't take any input:

```
import sympy as sp

x=Symbol("x")

def f_approx(x, x_0 = 0, n = 10, f = sin(x)):
    
    y = 0
    
    for i in range(0, n):
            
        v = diff(f, x, i)[text]
        
        y = y + (v.evalf(subs={x: x_0})/factorial(i))*(x-x_0)**i
        
    return y

print(f_approx(0))
```

`ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: 0`

Would be nice, if someone could help me. I'm a python noob...

`display(Eq(S('T(x)'), f_approx(x)))` gives the right output `()=2.75573192239859⋅10−69−0.0001984126984126987+0.008333333333333335−0.1666666666666673+1.0`
but any integer input gives the error `ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: 0`

Comment: can you add the code that is missing so that this is [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 v = diff(f, x, i)[text]
```

Sympy diff function expects different argument, first one being a function (your f) and 2nd one being a symbol (x in your case).

If you do `print(f_approx(0))`

You are telling that `x` is an int with the value 0, but sympy diff is waiting for a sympy symbol

therefore you are calling `v = diff(f, 0, i)[text]` which is incorrect

if you do `print(f_approx(x))` you won't get the error anymore
I would advise you to look at sympy documentation to get a better insight at what diff does